# Sketch subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(z+1)=|z-1|$

Tags: complex-numbers

I am required to sketch the subset of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $\mathrm{Re}(z+1)=|z-1|$.

All that I have succeeded in as yet is determining the value of the imaginary part of $z$ in terms of its real part, by this method:

$$\begin{align}z=a+bi\\\Rightarrow \mathrm{Re}(z+1)=|z-1| \iff a+1 &=\sqrt{(a-1)^2+b^2}\\(a+1)^2 &=(a-1)^2+b^2 \\ b^2&=a^2+2a+1-(a^2-2a+1)\\&=4a\\b&=\pm2\sqrt{a}\\\mathrm{Im}(z)&=\pm2\sqrt{\mathrm{Re}(z)}\end{align}$$

I arrived at the same conclusion geometrically.

**Edit: How might I have concluded immediately that the equation described a parabola $4x=y^2$?**

Comment: No, that's the solution. It's just a parabola on it's side, $4x=y^2$.

Comment: Still, my method seems too convoluted. How might I have recognised immediately that it was a parabola?

Comment: You can see the left-hand side $\mathrm{Re}(z+1)$ as the (signed) distance from $z$ to the vertical __line__ through $-1\in\mathbb{C}$. And you can see the right-hand side $|z-1|$ as the distance from $z$ to the __point__ $1\in\mathbb{C}$. Hence the solution is the geometric locus of points $z$ whose distance to the fixed line (__directrix__) equals their distance to the fixed point (__focus__). So this corroborates the parabola description.

Comment: Damn, beat me to it Jeppe.

Anyway, that is the quickest way to the formula. I would hardily call it convoluted. It should be your natural response to a question like this. You should also recognise $y=\pm a\sqrt{x}$ as a sideways parabola since the square root is the inverse of the square(inverses mirror across $y=x$).